# How do i make a Windows Form which opens a Process as child window by using the toolbar

Tags: winforms

How do i make a Windows Form program which in the toolbar you do like File > Open and it shows a Windows Open file dialog and after you selected the exe it will create a child window with the program itself like i open App.exe
it should show then a child window with the icon and the Program Title and the program contents and is this even possible? I'm beginner on coding in WinForms this so i don't know how to do it.
Anyone can Send a code which does this? I never coded WinForms in my life im just asking here so i can learn some coding on WinForms
I've tried to find tutorials but there was none of them that helped me

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683): "it is technically legal.

It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws. ... I often see this question in the context of somebody who wants to grab a window belonging to another process and forcibly graft it into their own process ... things will definitely stop working if you change that other window from a top-level window to a child window."

Comment: oh so its not possible. alright i will do something else with child window's